# Iterative modularity

Tags: gephi

I have run modulartiy edge_weight/randomized at a resolution of 1, atleast 20 times on the same network. This is the same network I have created based on the following rule. Two nodes are related if they have atleast one item in common. Every time I run modularity I get a little different node distribution among communities. Additionally, I get 9 or 10 communities but it is never consistent. Any comment or help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the answer is in the randomizing part of the algorithm. You can find more details here:

https://github.com/gephi/gephi/wiki/Modularity

https://sites.google.com/site/findcommunities/

http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/0803.0476

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it. Is it correct if i ran modularity 100 times on the same network and pick a consensus network based on relationships that stay atleast a certain percentage (say 60%) or higher along the 100 runs and call that as my final modularity. I am picking 60% based on network topology parameter such as highest clustering coeff. I am building the modularities with only those edges that were called 60% or higher by the modularity algorithm along the 100 trials.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem using consensus clustering. Here is the paper that describes it. One way to get the optimum clusters without having to solve them in a high-dimensional space using spectral clustering would be to run the algorithm repeatedly until no more partitions can be achieved. Here is the article and complete explanation details:

SCIENTIFIC REPORTS | 2 : 336 | DOI: 10.1038/srep00336
Consensus clustering in complex networks Andrea Lancichinetti & Santo Fortunato

The consensus matrix. Let us suppose that we wish to combine nP partitions found by a clustering algorithm on a network with n vertices. The consensus matrix D is an n x n matrix, whose entry Dij indicates the number of partitions in which vertices i and j of the network were assigned to the same cluster, divided by the number of partitions nP. The matrix D is usually much denser than the adjacency matrix A of the original network, because in the consensus matrix there is an edge between any two vertices which have cooccurred in the same cluster at least once. On the other hand, the weights are large only for those vertices which are most frequently coclustered, whereas low weights indicate that the vertices are probably at the boundary between different (real) clusters, so their classification in the same cluster is unlikely and essentially due to noise. We wish to maintain the large weights and to drop the low ones, therefore a filtering procedure is in order. Among the other things, in the absence of filtering the consensus matrix would quickly grow into a very dense matrix, which would make the application of any clustering algorithm computationally expensive.We discard all entries of D below a threshold t. We stress that there might be some noisy vertices whose edges could all be below the threshold, and they would be not connected anymore. When this happens, we just connect them to their neighbors with highest weights, to keep the graph connected all along the procedure.

Next we apply the same clustering algorithm to D and produce another set of partitions, which is then used to construct a new consensus matrix D9, as described above. The procedure is iterated until the consensus matrix turns into a block diagonal matrix Dfinal, whose weights equal 1 for vertices in the same block and 0 for vertices in different blocks. The matrix Dfinal delivers the community structure of the original network. In our calculations typically one iteration is sufficient to lead to stable results. We remark that in order to use the same clustering method all along, the latter has to be able to detect clusters in weighted networks, since the consensus matrix is weighted. This is a necessary constraint on the choice of the methods for which one could use the procedure proposed here. However, it is not a severe limitation,as most clustering algorithms in the literature can handle weighted networks or can be trivially extended to deal with them.